# Changing font size in Kile's Log and Messages window

Tags: fonts, windows, kile

I am using Kile 2.9.60 in the KDE Development Platform 4.10.2 on a Dell XPS 15 laptop under Windows 10. I know how to change the editor fonts via "Configure Kile" > "Fonts & Colors" > "Font" > "Size", via "ctrl" + "+" or via scrolling, but this does not effect the fonts in the Log and Messages window, which remain utterly unreadable. How to enlarge these?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about Windows behavior, but in Linux the "low windows" of Kile have font that cannot be changed by Kile options. Log and Messages windows can be changed going here

[image]

Then going here:

[image]

And finally choosing this (you have to customize general font)

[image]

But this would change not only the windows you want change, but almost all fonts in KDE: it doesn't look very practical, and it is useless in Linux, were fonts in this windows are **not** unreadable. Maybe the best thing would be leave Windows and jump to Linux :-) (I know, you can't to do that overnight, this solution would take time...). You can change Konsole windows font too by clicking with the right of the mouse on it

[image]

and then choosing dimension here

[image]

*Resuming*, if Windows Kile acts like Linux one, you have to try to change general fonts of operating system: trying to change fonts of this windows acting con Kile options will be useless.